# System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
string dataResult = GetData("http://192.168.1.119/Test/api/TestApp/LoginCheck?username=" + UName.Text + "&pswrd=" + Pswrd.Text + "");

private string GetData(string url)
    {
        string Result = "false";
        try
        {   
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                Result = client.DownloadString(@"" + url + "");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string msg = e.Message;
            Result = "false";
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

Hi Friends I am getting Connection time out error in this line

```
 Result = client.DownloadString(@"" + url + "");
```

But in the web it is working fine. Please help any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably the Webclient is not able to connect because you use double quotes around the url. You can read this in the API documentation here [MDSN WebClient.DownloadString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is also a sample included. Please try to change your line to:

```
 Result = client.DownloadString(url);
```

However, I saw your url for the request. You should **never ever** send usernames and passwords in a URL query string. Please consider at least using [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) over HTTPS for the simplest way to authenticate users, which puts the username and the password in the HTTP authorization header.